# use properties file in java eclipse for deployment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, properties-file

newbie Java developer over here. I have the following question. Basically, I have java project structured like the java attachment (picture). I have a hibernate configuration file ( **oracle-hibernate.cfg.xml** ) AND a Spring configuration file ( **dbcontext.xml** ).

I also have a database properties file ( **database.properties** ).

[image]

**oracle-hibernate-cfg.xml** has the following for an Oracle connection

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">testing</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@scar:1521:DSV</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
```

**dbcontext.xml** has the following for Oracle connection

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
```

**database.properties** has the following information:

```
database.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@scar:1521:DSV
database.username=test
database.password=testing
```

**QUESTION**
How can I fix tis so that **database.properties** is a single point of input for  **BOTH** **oracle-hibernate-cfg.xml** and **dbcontext.xml**

TIA

Comment: You don't need all these hibernate.commection properties in the hibernate configuration, since you're defining a datasource in the spring app, and this datasource should thus be used by your hibernate session factory, which should also be defined as a spring bean. I would do myself a favor, stop using xml files, and use spring boot and spring-data-jpa.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Thanks for the response. So what you are saying is that I should get rid of the oracle-hibernate-cfg.xml file and just rely on the dbcontext.xml file (and to use some kind of dependency injection for the sessionFactory references in the code)?

Comment: @JB Nizet - Should I leave the "properties" files in the "src/main/resources" directory or move them to the "Deployed Resources/webapp/WEB-INF" directory?

Comment: @JB Nzet Again, I am just learning all of this. Is using "spring boot" and "spring-data-jpa" easier than using XML configuration files?

Comment: Yes, definitely easier. But as anything else, it requires reading and learning. The spring-boot documentation is a pleasure to read.

Comment: OK, will do so. In the meantime, do you think I should get rid of the reference to the "oracle-hibernate-cfg.xml file"? It was generated using Hibernate tools. I was thinking that I could. Afterwards, just focus on getting the injection for the session factory working for DAO functions(?)

Comment: Yes, you don't need a hibernate config file since spring can configure hibernate directly. You'd better stop using the SessionFactory, and use Hibernate through the standard JPA API instead.